RC Airplane Questions
I'm making a RC Airplane using Sunboard and Cardboard. The wing is about 80cm long, with a wing profile looking like 
I also connected a A2212 1000kv Brushless motor with a 10x4.5 Inch Propeller. To power all the electronics, I used a 2200mAH 10C 3S Li-Ion battery pack. It can provide a thrust of about 600 grams. The airplane weighs about 850 grams.
Now, my question is whether the airplane can fly, since the thrust provided by the propeller is lesser than the weight of the plane.
Any help and advice would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Would be more on-topic at Drones.SE.

I put it here since I wanted to indirectly know if the lift produced by the wing is enough

Yes, actually this is the same question which got migrated from aviation S.E to here
